# How do I deal with one predicate with multiple answers?

Tags: prolog

Let's say I have a predicate which looks to see if someone has a sister.

Then there are - in my opinion - two possibilities:

1) Someone uses sister(X,Y) so the user wants a list of all the persons with their sisters.
2) Someone uses sister(Person,Y) so the user wants to see all sisters of that person.

Then the outcome can also be one of three possibilities:

1) One answer is found.
2) Multiple answers are found. 
2) nothing is found.

Now I can do this in Prolog (pseudocode)

if X and Y are not subsitained  and multiple answers are found then print this "All the sisters pairs are" 
else 
   if X and Y are not subsitained  and one answer is found then print this "The only sister of pair is" 
  else if X is substained and multiple answers are found then print "The sisters of Person1 are"

So, this will be a very big if then.
Is there a cleaner way to deal with this ?

Roelof

edit 1 :

I thought of this way:

```
display_sisters(X,Y) :-
      var(X), 
      var(Y), 
      setof (x-y,sisters_of(X,Y),Sisters), 
      <<check if Sisters is non-empty>>>
       write "The sisters are" , 
        <<print answers>>

display_sisters(X,Y) :-
      var(X), 
      var(Y), 
      setof (x-y,sisters_of(X,Y),Sisters), 
      <<check if Sisters is empty>>>
       write "There are no sisters" ,
```

Comment: By "subsitained" do you mean "instantiated"?

Comment: yep, sorry for the confusing I made. I think the answer which is giving works but Im a beginner and this script is way much more then I can chew.

Answer (score 0):

No, and you forget to say what to print when there are no answers, or duplicates.

Your requirements are very specific, and the code will be cluttered by details.
Some Prolog make available [portray](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=portray/1)/1, but you should apply it to a list...

Something generic could be (using setof/3 to avoid duplicates)

```
print_answers(Query, One, More, None) :-
    Query =.. [Functor, A1, A2],
    ( nonvar(One) ; One = 'The only ~s of ~w is ~w' ),
    ( nonvar(More) ; More = 'All the ~ss pairs are ~w' ),
    ( nonvar(None) ; None = 'None ~s found' ),
    (   setof(A1-A2, Query, Answers)
    ->  (   Answers = [_]
        ->  format(One, [Functor, A1, A2])
        ;   format(More, [Functor, Answers])
        )
    ;   format(None, [Functor])
    ).
```

that yields

```
sister(a,b).
sister(a,c).

?- print_answers(sister(a,X),_,_,_).
All the sisters pairs are [a-b,a-c]

?- print_answers(sister(a,b),_,_,_).
The only sister of a is b
```

but imho is not worth the effort...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you're looking for very specific language and display of results depending upon conditions. @CapelliC's answer is the way to condense the result into the most concise predicate using `format` and the Prolog "if-then-else" pattern.

Here's a slightly more verbose solution, without using `format`, but using the "if-then-else" pattern explained later. Perhaps this will take you a step in the right direction, but then reconsider @CapelliC's solution for a more general treatment (which can be used for a variety of sibling predicates) after you've had a chance to research how Prolog `format` works. (`format` is a lot like `printf` in C, but formatting symbols are different.)

```
% Display all sister pairs
%
display_sisters(X, Y) :-
    var(X), var(Y),
    setof(X-Y, sisters_of(X, Y), Sisters),
    length(Sisters, Number),
    (   Number =:= 0
    ->  write('No one has a sister')
    ;   (   Number =:= 1
        ->  write('The only person with sister is: '),
            write(Sisters)
        ;   write('All the persons with sisters are: '),
            write(Sisters)
        )
    ), nl.

% Display sisters of a given person
%
display_sisters(X, Y) :-
    nonvar(X), var(Y),
    setof(Y, sisters_of(X, Y), Sisters),
    length(Sisters, Number),
    (   Number =:= 0
    ->  write('Person '), write(X), write(' has no sister')
    ;   (   Number =:= 1
        ->  write('The only sister '), write(X), write(' has is '),
            write(Sisters)
        ;   write('All of '), write(X), write('''s sisters are: '),
            write(Sisters)
        )
    ), nl.
```

This makes a lot of use of the "if-then-else" construct in Prolog. It could probably be done without it, but it would be come even more verbose and a bit cumbersome. The "if-then-else" helps condense the logic.

The construct:

```
P1 -> P2.
```

Will query `P1` and, if it succeeds, query `P2`. Otherwise, it will fail. Combined with the OR (`;`) in Prolog, you can do an "if-then-else":

```
P1 -> P2 ; P3.
```

If `P1` succeeds, then Prolog will move on to the `P2` query. Otherwise, `P1 -> P2` fails and it will do `P3` (because of the OR, `;`). Due to operator precedence, you need parentheses if you have multiple statements in or around this construct. `,` has higher precedence than `;`, and `;` is higher than `->`. So a more elaborate pattern would look like:

```
P1,
P2,
(  P3    % Start of the if-then-else : P3 is the condition
-> P4,   % P4, P5 are both in the true leg due to precedence of ','
   P5
;  P6,   % P6, P7 are both the false leg due to precedence of ','
   P7
),...    % End of the if-then-else
```

In the code shown for the answer, there's another if-then-else as the "false" leg, so it just has it's own grouping:

```
...
(  P1       % The condition
-> P2       % 'true' branch is P2
;  (  P3    % 'false' branch is another if-then-else pattern
   -> P4
   ;  P5,
      P6
   )
)
```

When you're wanting to do more elaborate things in Prolog, you're going to need to "hit the books" on learning some of its other built-in capabilities ("if-then-else", `=../2`, `format`, etc). You'll learn more about Prolog if you study and work through @CapelliC's answer.